# TypeError: res.status is not a function expess app

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm trying to create a function that generates a discount voucher, and I'm getting an error as "TypeError: res.status is not a function at the controller."

here is my discount Controller :

```
function coupongenerator ()  {
   var coupon = '';
   var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      coupon += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
   }
   return coupon;
}
```

```
exports.createCoupon = () => {
    let isExistDiscount = false;
    do {
       let myDiscountCode = coupongenerator()
       let newDiscountCode = new Coupon({
          code: myDiscountCode,
          isPercent: true,
          amount:30 ,
          expireDate: '',
          isActive: true
       });
       newDiscountCode.save(function (err,res) {
          if (err) {
             if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
                // Duplicate code detected
                isExistDiscount = true;
             }
          }
          res.status(200).send('yes');
       });
   } while (isExistDiscount);
}
```

Comment: `req`and `res` are variables passed from express toyour function call so, you need on `createCoupon = () => {}` pass `(req, res)` to get the request and result objects.

Comment: thanks a lot, i change it to createcoupon=(req,res)=>{} and it works

Answer (score 0):

The "res" object you are trying to access is actually the response coming after saving the Mongo document in callback function. res.status works with HTTP res object in express which generally will be a function parameter of a controller. Just check if your controller variable identifier and the callback identifier is same, which will shadow the controller variable. Hence the scope of res is the res in callback param which do not have a function called status in it. If that's the reason change one of the identifier names.